# How does the displacement operator act on number states $|n\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-optics

The displacement operator generates the coherent state out of the vacuum.

$$\hat D(\alpha)|0\rangle = |\alpha\rangle$$

but I am wondering what the meaning of a displacement operator acting upon a number state with $n \neq 0$ is.

For example, is $\hat D(\alpha)|1\rangle$ meaningful?

I have not been able to find any mention of this online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed meaningful; they're called, surprisingly enough, [displaced number states](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22displaced+number+state%22&btnG=), and they've appeared on this site e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129664/8563) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54063/shift-operator-integral-calculus-involving-hermite-polynomials). It's hard to say anything else about them without knowing what exactly you want to know about them, though.

Comment: My apologies, it seems obvious now that you say it, but for whatever reason my search terms weren't picking this up. I think I can find the general information I need online now. Thank you

Comment: @jm22b No worries. It happened to me, too, except that I had done *all* of the calculations in §3.4 and 3.5 of [my bachelor's thesis](http://132.248.9.195/ptb2011/septiembre/0673328/Index.html) by the time I hit on the right search term. That did teach me the value of a thorough literature search before you calculate, though ;-). As the saying goes: "A few weeks of developing and testing can save a whole afternoon in the library".